# How to write test case for EmptyComponent in Jest

Tags: reactjs, function, jestjs, code-coverage, react-testing-library

Below is the code in my component

export default () => null;

How to write test case for this to get coverage for the function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just a function you can do this:

```
import Empty from './Empty'

test('renders null', () => {
  const res = Empty()
  expect(res).toBeNull()
})
```